# Best practices for context parameter in addObserver (KVO)

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

I was wondering what you should set the Context pointer in KVO when you are observing a property.  I'm just starting to use KVO and I haven't gleaned too much from the documentation.  I see on this page: http://www.jakeri.net/2009/12/custom-callout-bubble-in-mkmapview-final-solution/ the author does this:

```
[annView addObserver:self
forKeyPath:@"selected"
options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
context:GMAP_ANNOTATION_SELECTED];
```

And then in the callback, does this:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
ofObject:(id)object
change:(NSDictionary *)change
context:(void *)context{

NSString *action = (NSString*)context;


if([action isEqualToString:GMAP_ANNOTATION_SELECTED]){
```

I'm assuming in this scenario, the author just creates a string to be identified later in the callback.

Then in iOS 5 Pushing the Limits book, I see he does this:

```
[self.target addObserf:self forKeyPath:self.property options:0 context:(__bridge void *)self];
```

callback:

```
if ((__bridge id)context == self) {
}
else {
   [super observeValueForKeyPath .......];
}
```

I was wondering if there is a standard or best practices to pass into the context pointer?

Answer (score 110):

The important thing is (generally speaking) that you use **something** (as opposed to nothing) and that whatever you use be **unique** and **private to your use of it**.

The primary pitfall here happens when you have an observation in one of your classes, and then someone subclasses your class, and they add another observation of the same observed object and the same keyPath. If your original `observeValueForKeyPath:...` implementation only checked `keyPath`, or the observed `object`, or even both, that might not be sufficient to know that it's *your* observation being called back. Using a `context` whose value is unique and private to you allows you to be much more certain that a given call to `observeValueForKeyPath:...` is the call you're expecting it to be.

This would matter if, for instance, you registered only for `didChange` notifications, but a subclass registers for the same object and keyPath with the `NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior` option. If you weren't filtering calls to `observeValueForKeyPath:...` using a `context` (or checking the change dictionary), your handler would execute multiple times, when you only expected it to execute once. It's not hard to imagine how this might cause problems.

The pattern I use is:

```
static void * const MyClassKVOContext = (void*)&MyClassKVOContext;
```

This pointer will point to its own location, and that location is unique (no other static or global variable can have this address, nor can any heap or stack allocated object ever have this address -- it's a pretty strong, although admittedly not *absolute*, guarantee), thanks to the linker. The `const` makes it so that the compiler will warn us if we ever try to write code that would change the value of the pointer, and lastly, `static` makes it private to this file, so no one outside this file can obtain a reference to it (again, making it more likely to avoid collisions).

One pattern I would specifically caution *against* using is one that appeared in the question:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    NSString *action = (NSString*)context;
    if([action isEqualToString:GMAP_ANNOTATION_SELECTED]) {
```

`context` is declared to be a `void*`, meaning that that's all the guarantee that can be made about what it is. By casting it to an `NSString*` you're opening a big box of potential badness. If someone else happens to have a registration that *doesn't* use an `NSString*` for the `context` parameter, this approach will crash when you pass the non-object value to `isEqualToString:`. Pointer equality (or alternatively `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` equality) are the only safe checks that can be used with a `context` value.

Using `self` as a `context` is a common approach. It's better than nothing, but has much weaker uniquing and privacy, since other objects (not to mention subclasses) have access to the value of `self` and might use it as a `context` (causing ambiguity), unlike with the approach I suggested above.

Also remember, it's not *just* subclasses that might cause pitfalls here; Although it's arguably a rare pattern, there's nothing that preventing another object from registering your object for new KVO observations.

For improved readability, you could also wrap this up in a preprocessor macro like:

```
#define MyKVOContext(A) static void * const A = (void*)&A;
```

Comment: This is a truly well-written little essay and I'm surprised that the OP has not accepted it.

Comment: What is the benefit of having the pointer point to its own location (as opposed just declaring the pointer with no value)?

Comment: KVO treats the context like an integer. It doesn't care what it "points to", so as mentioned, having it point to itself gives good uniquing (i.e. there can't be an object malloced later that happens to have the same address.)

Comment: A more interesting reason not to use `self` as the context is that `self` is shared by code in subclasses and superclasses. For instance, if you have a superclass **Person**, a subclass of that called **Employee**, and a subclass of that called **Manager** they'll all have the same `self`. And they probably shouldn't share the context, as otherwise future changes in **Manager** could affect **Person**.

Comment: This is exactly what I was getting at when I said "private to your use of it".

Comment: So is there a reason I should not simply define context as:  void *context = (__bridge void *)(self);

Comment: `self` being a pointer to an object is pretty much the definition of "not private to this use of it." So yeah, there's plenty of reason not to use it as a KVO context.

Comment: I disagree with this pattern. A KVO context isn't for identifying the class, instead it is for identifying the action that should take place when any number of key paths are changed.  E.g. both name and age keypaths should all result updateView being called. Using a context pointer this can be done fast without checking doing a key path string comparison.

Comment: Did you actually *read* my answer? Nowhere in it did I suggest that a KVO context is about "identifying the class". That can be done trivially from the `object` parameter.

Answer (score 19):

The KVO context should be a pointer to a static variable, as [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3044537) demonstrates.  Typically, I find myself doing the following:

Near the top of my file `ClassName.m` I'll have the line

```
static char ClassNameKVOContext = 0;
```

When I begin observing the `aspect` property on `targetObject` (an instance of `TargetClass`) I'll have

```
[targetObject addObserver:self
               forKeyPath:PFXKeyTargetClassAspect
                  options://...
                  context:&ClassNameKVOContext];
```

where PFXKeyTargetClassAspect is an `NSString *` defined in `TargetClass.m` to be equal to `@"aspect"` and declared `extern` in `TargetClass.h`.  (Of course PFX is just a placeholder for the prefix you're using in your project.)  This gives me the advantage of autocomplete and protects me from typos.

When I finish observing `aspect` on `targetObject` I'll have

```
[targetObject removeObserver:self
                  forKeyPath:PFXKeyTargetClassAspect
                     context:&ClassNameKVOContext];
```

In order to avoid too much indentation in my implementation of `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`, I like to write

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (context != &ClassNameKVOContext) {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
        return;
    }

    if ([object isEqual:targetObject]) {
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:PFXKeyTargetClassAspect]) {
            //targetObject has changed the value for the key @"aspect".
            //do something about it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to add unit tests to how I handle things in the `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`. The problem I have is that I'm observing read-only properties on an object that I can't change in the unit tests to trigger KVO, hence I need to invoke manually the `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method in the unit test directly. But when I pass to that call and pass the context, it always is different and my unit test always fails.  Do you have any idea how to pass a context that is the same in the unit tests?

Comment: I disagree with this pattern. A KVO context isn't for identifying the class, instead it is for identifying the action that should take place when any number of key paths are changed. E.g. both name and age keypaths should all result updateView being called. Using a context pointer this can be done fast without checking doing a key path string comparison.

Answer (score 4):

I think the better way would be to implement it as apple's doc says:

> The address of a uniquely named static variable within your class makes a good context.

```
static void *PersonAccountBalanceContext = &PersonAccountBalanceContext;
static void *PersonAccountInterestRateContext = &PersonAccountInterestRateContext;
```

see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252-SW4).