# observeValueForKeyPath: called for every property, not just the observed property

Tags: key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller

I have an NSArrayController (itemsController) which hold an array of MyObject. This controller is tied to an NSTableView which has several columns, all bound to different properties.

I want to observe one of these properties elsewhere in the app.

```
[[self itemsController] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedObjects.someProperty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

In the callback:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

I am getting called whenever any property in the selection changes, but I only want to be called when someProperty in a selected object changes.

How can I prevent all these other calls when nothing has really changed?

Observing @"selection.someProperty" has the same results.

Comment: I find this hard to believe. There's no way to observe *all* properties of an object. How are you changing the properties? What `keyPath` and `change` dictionary are you receiving? Are you explicitly calling `-will/didChangeValueForKey:` or similar methods? Are you overriding KVC or KVO methods (e.g. `-setValue:forKey:`)? Is the array controller doing filtering or sorting? Is `automaticallyRearrangesObjects` enabled? By the way, there's no question: you should be binding through `selection` and **not** `selectedObjects`.

Answer (score 1):

You also get notified when `selectedObjects` or `selection` changes. If you want to get notified when `someProperty` changes then you have to observe `someProperty` of the selected objects and remove and add observers when the selection changes.

The superclasses of your observing class could also be observing. Use the `context` parameter to recognize your notifications. See [Best practices for context parameter in addObserver (KVO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719864/best-practices-for-context-parameter-in-addobserver-kvo)